# ListView and ContextMenu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

Is it possible to implements working with context menu inside ListView class? It is no onContextItemSelected() method here. I don't want write a code with context menu inside Activity class.

Thank you!

Comment: What class do you mean? You extend ListView? Or it's a custom Adapter implementation?

Comment: It's hard to understand what is being asked here. Are you asking about implementing a `ContextMenu` inside of a `ListView`? As for not wanting to write code within an `Activity`, frankly, that's **A Bad Idea**.

Comment: yes, I want implement ContextMenu inside a ListView class, because ContextMenu relatives to a ListView class, not to an Activity, but ListView hasn't neccesary method (It has onCreateContextMenu, but hasn't onContextItemSelected()... Can't understand android developers' logic...)

Comment: Android developer's logic is this: `Activity` is your basic building block. It holds layout items and is the basic interface between the application and the user. `ListView` and other widgets are layout items to be hosted inside an `Activity`.

Comment: A rough analogy would be as follows: The `Activity` is the toolkit. It holds your tools (layout widgets and code) but is empty without them. However, it's much easier to manage your tools with a toolkit rather than carrying them all around in your pocket.

Answer (score 1):

This would break the Android UI pattern pretty badly. `Activity` (and in recent versions `Fragment`) is responsible for displaying widgets like menus. Pushing this functionality down into a `View` will make your app a mystery.

You can get what you want by defining an interface, say `ContextPopupDelegate` with functions to build and handle selections in a context menu, then have your new `View` implement this interface. Any activity using your view delegates to the interface methods.

Comment: It sounds strange for me... Why does realization of ContextMenu  which connected with ListView should be placed in another logic module (i.e. Activity class)? I see your explanation about Android UI principles but it strange for me about logical connections of this things... Thank you much!

Comment: There are good and bad aspects of the "Android way" of consolidating UI code in Activities. `Swing` for example lets you put things wherever you want. But I find Android code generally easier to read, albeit more bothersome to write.  Since code is written by one person but often read by many, there seems to be a net profit in the Android way. Certainly others' opinions will differ.